# Building windows forms in C

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi, controls

So far, I've been able to create a window in C, and add a button and edit box to that window. But, where can I find an exhaustive list of the system classes for all the form controls? I can't remember where I found BUTTON and EDIT--is there a LABEL? LISTBOX? CHECKBOX? COMBOBOX? etc.

Then, how would I use those built in windows functions...I think they're called common controls? Like open a file, save as, print, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are: they are on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773169(VS.85).aspx).

But I agree with Zifre that you better use a gui-framework for stuff like this.
There are more like these, e.g. [MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e(VS.80).aspx) or [WTL](http://wtl.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: huh, that whole section was missing from my copy of MSDN. Oh well.

Answer (score 10):

You will go insane if you try to write raw Win32 code with C. If you can use C++, I highly suggest using [Qt](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/), if not, use [Gtk](http://www.gtk.org/).

Comment: Your answer is predicated on only sane people trying to raw Win32 code (otherwise it would be impossible to go insane).  I would say the opposite is much more likely.  Maybe a better statement would be "You will be insane if you try to write raw Win32 code with C".  :)

Comment: @JaredPar: I guess I must be insane then; I've tried it before (it's not much fun...)

Comment: @Zifre, I haven't had the pleasure of doing it much myself but I've code reviewed some rather large features that did and it was ... challenging.

Answer (score 3):

Some people like things pure

[stromcode](http://www.stromcode.com/2008/03/01/cwin32-tutorials/) [zetcode](http://www.zetcode.com/tutorials/winapi/) [forgers](http://winprog.org/tutorial/) and heck if you're really feeling crazy, [win32 in assembly](http://win32assembly.online.fr/)

Comment: win32 in assembly: masochism at its purest

Comment: one day, I will write a full-scale win32 application in assembly. It's going to be incredible. Just you wait. @boboboetc, thanks for the links

Comment: @CarsonMyers, where is it now?

Comment: @DesmondGold after thirteen years of constant work I finally have a working popup window

Answer (score 1):

For the open dialogs and so on you want the Common Dialogs section -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645524(VS.85).aspx.

Whilst on the subject of Win32, if you're using the file dialogs and therefore file names you may also find the shell functions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776426(VS.85).aspx) handy -- in particular, the `Path`*XXX* ones. I wish I'd known about these when I was getting started.